# Test custom jQuery 'class' in Jasmine

Tags: jquery, jasmine

I'm kind of stuck trying to test this extended jQuery function.

```
jQuery.fn.checkModule = function checkModule() {

/* Code */

}}
```

So I started out with this:

```
describe("checkModule", function() {
    var widget;

    beforeEach(function() {
        widget = jQuery.fn.checkModule();
    });

    it("should be a jQuery object", function() {
        expect(widget instanceof jQuery).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to initialize. How can I test these functions/this 'class'?

Comment: Why to you believe it should be an instance of jQuery? What does your function return?

Comment: (I've not written this code). It appears to return nothing, it contains some functions and some other jQuery stuff that iterates over input fields.

Comment: If the function returns nothing then `widget` will be `undefined`. Maybe you should focus on test the stuff that happens inside the function.

Comment: It does indeed console.log to `undefined`. I am trying to test the internal functions.. but I don't know how to reach them